# Issue while Running Hive in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, hive

I have followed the below steps to configure Hive 0.8.1 in Cygwin. Hive is started properly as I am getting Hive CLI when type hive. But while running any command in hive its not returning any response and the command is running into a infinite loop.

Please help if I miss anything.

Steps to configure Hive

1. Chown of the hive folder
2. Change permission of hive folder to `755`
3. Set this to `hive-site.xml`

   ```
   <property>
       <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
       <value>/home/yourusername/mydir</value>
       <description>Scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
     </property>
   ```
4. Put the following in the hive lib folder:

   ```
   hadoop-0.20-core.jar
   hive/lib/hive-exec-0.7.1.jar
   hive/lib/hive-jdbc-0.7.1.jar
   hive/lib/hive-metastore-0.7.1.jar
   hive/lib/hive-service-0.7.1.jar
   hive/lib/libfb303.jar
   lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
   slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
   slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
   ```
5. In `hive-env.sh` change following:

   ```
   # Set HADOOP_HOME to point to a specific hadoop install directory

   #here instead of path what i have given you give your own path where hadoop #isthere
   export HADOOP_HOME=/home/user/Hadoop/hadoop-0.20.205

   # Hive Configuration Directory can be controlled by:

   #here you specify the conf directory path of hive
   export HIVE_CONF_DIR=/home/user/Hadoop/hive-0.8.1/conf

   #Folder containing extra ibraries required for hive compilation/execution

   #can be controlled by:

   #here you specify the lib file directory, here you can specify the lib
   ```

Comment: It would be useful to have details of how to reproduce this, such as the exact commands you use, including the output, and how you know it's hitting an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, i could successfully run HIVE after starting all hadoop deamons like namenode,datanode,jobtracker & Task Tracker. And Run queries from files using "hive -f " insted of writing queries directly at hive command prompt. You may also use bin/hive -e 'SHOW TABLES'

Comment: I am trying to run in the local mode where I do not have hadoop deamons like NN, DN, JT and TT. I am facing the same issue. I am able to open PIG/GRUNT and Hive shells on cygwin but when I type something it goes in the infinite look and kind of hangs. I have added more details here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010482/hive-and-pig-grunt-shell-hangs-on-cygwin Please check if you help. Thanks in advance.