# Hive and PIG/Grunt shell hangs on cygwin

Tags: windows-7, hadoop, cygwin, hive, apache-pig

I am running Hadoop on local mode on my windows 7 machine (32 Bit).

I've installed HIVE/PIG/Hadoop/Java6 all on the C: drive.
I am using Cygwin version: 2.819.
I've mounted C: on the cygwin.
I am able to run hadoop commands from the cygwin terminal for example : `fs -ls` etc.
I am also able to start grunt and hive shells.

But the real problem is:
Any command I enter on grunt shell (example: `fs -ls` or `records = LOAD.....` ) I do not see any output, it kind of hangs. Similarly with the hive prompt if I give the command as show tables ; I do not see any output just cursor keeps on blinking! Any keyboard inputs and gives NOTHING. System appears to be doing NOTHING.

To me everything looks fine but definitely something is going wrong :-)

I am not sure if I am missing something.
Any help will be highly appreciated. I am attaching my classpath and environment variables from .bashrc file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/c/Java/jdk1.6.0_34
export HADOOP_HOME=/c/Hadoop
export PIG_HOME=/c/PIG
export HIVE_HOME=/c/Hive

export HADOOP_BIN=$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop

export PATH=$PATH:/c/Java/jdk1.6.0_34/bin

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin

export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Anything interesting in the logs?

Comment: I am not getting any logs!

Comment: Hi, even i was trying, i am able to setup hadoop without cygwin followed http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/757934/Apache-Hadoop-for-Windows-Platform, but not able to do multi cluster. Even with cygwin still keep on getting Error Could not find or load main class, when ever i start the dfs and yarn. what hadoop version used? built the source or got binary?               Thanks If could give some suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above links did not help in my case. The following solution - to change the [CYGWIN shortcut properties](http://hadooptips.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/hive-and-piggrunt-shell-hangs-on-cygwin) helped.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug. Other people are reporting the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081246/cygwin-and-apache-pig-a-perplexing-pseudo-grunt) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315180/pig-in-grunt-mode). Someone solved this problem following the tutorial linked [here](https://itellity.wordpress.com/2009/12/06/setting-up-hadoop-on-windows-vista/); you can try that and see if it fixes it in your case.

Comment: Thanks I went through those links and tried to follow the tutorial link also but it did not work in my case!